# Insert a link into MatSnackBar

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Is it possible to insert a link into the Angular Material 2 `MatSnackBarModule`?

I've tried doing it inside the text, but it displays the html as text.

```
const text = '<a routerLink="/login">login</a>';
this.snackBar.open(text, 'OK', {
  duration: environment.snackBarTime,
});
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to create your own custom snackbar component for links:

`custom-snackbar.component.html`:

```html
<a routerLink="/login">Login</a>
```

`custom-snackbar.component.ts`:

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-snackbar',
  templateUrl: 'custom-snackbar.component.html'
})
export class CustomSnackBar {}
```

Also, ensure that this custom snackbar is declared under `declarations` and `entryComponents` in your app's module file:

`app.module.ts`:

```ts
import { CustomSnackBar } from './custom-snackbar/custom-snackbar.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material';
// Other module imports here

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
      CustomSnackBar
      // Other declarations here
    ],
    imports: [
      MatSnackBarModule,
      // Other modules here
    ],
    entryComponents: [
      CustomSnackBar
    ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Thirdly, to open this snackbar component, call the `openFromComponent` method of `MatSnackBar`:

`app.component.ts`:

```ts
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';
import { CustomSnackBar } from './custom-snackbar/custom-snackbar.component';
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private snackbar: MatSnackBar){}

  login() {
    /*
     * `openFromComponent` accepts two properties:
     * The first param is `ComponentType<any>`, or your snackbar 
     * component
     * The second param is `MatSnackBarConfig`. In this sample,
     * I'll be using the duration param.
     */
    this.snackbar.openFromComponent(CustomSnackBar, { duration: 5000 };
  }
}
```

Lastly, I recommend you to add a class to the anchor element in the snackbar as it can't be seen clearly.

Here's a [**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/snackbar-with-html-so) for you to play around with.

Comment: Thanks! A very clever solution!

Comment: its working fine but in console i am getting this error  `ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: 'visible-bottom'. It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook ?`

Comment: @Developer this is a known bug with angular and rxjs. You can google about it.

Comment: @Edric : how to add the Action button (such as OK to close) in your example when you use openFromComponent? Thanks

Comment: @Iteration, add it to the custom snackbar component, and use the close method defined in the component. like so: ```<button mat-button (click)="close()">OK</button>```

Answer (score 18):

**If all you want to do is navigate the user when they click on the snackbar action**, then there is a much more straightforward solution to this which does not involve creating a dedicated component.

```
this.snackBar.open('Record has been created', 'View Record', { duration: 5000})
  .onAction()
  .subscribe(() => this.router.navigateByUrl('/app/user/detail'));
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party here, but you can also create a template inside the component's html file and then call it from the typescript file using `snackbar.openFromTemplate()`.

This is pretty similar to @Edric's answer, but allows for a dynamic message rather than a static one.

There is a great demo of how to do this here: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/dev-app/snack-bar/snack-bar-demo.ts

Comment: This is a nice solution if you are only using that particular template once for that component. I will certainly employ this when I come across this particular use case.