# Inserted link to MatSnackBar not added to Angular tree

Tags: angular, angular-material

This is a follow-up question to this thread [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949233/insert-a-link-into-matsnackbar)

I have the problem that the link is not working in the `MatSnackBar`. I already had a custom component which is pretty much looking like the working example above. However, `<a routerLink="/login">Login</a>` is the same in the DOM. As I understand it, it should have been transformed by Angular to something like

```html
<a _ngcontent-c2="" routerlink="/login" ng-reflect-router-link="/logins" href="#/login">Login</a>
```

Could it be that I have to add the component via `ViewContainerRef` to the Angular tree?

Angular 5.0.3, angular/material 5.0.0

Snackbar.component.html

```
<div id='snackbar'>
   <div id='snackbar-message'>
    {{message}}
   </div>

   <span class='k-icon k-i-x k-icon-md' id='snackbar-action' (click)='close()' title='Close popup'></span>
</div>
```

popup.service excerpt

```
this.snackbar = this.popup.openFromComponent(SnackbarComponent, { panelClass: ['popup-error'] });
this.setSnackbarMessage(message);
```

Comment: Do you have `@angular/router`?

Comment: Yes, i am also using this package. Why?

Comment: So what's your code? I'm just checking if you really installed Angular Router. Can you also add your package dependencies?

Comment: `"@angular/router": "5.1.2"` is the version I am using. Everything else is working as intended.

Comment: What's your code setup?

Comment: I have added some code snippets.