# How to add html Content on Snackbar in angular material?

Tags: angular-material, angular5

I have created toaster(snackbar) for response message.
I want to add an html content on toaster(snackbar) so that multiple message can be  display in proper format.

**I have tried**

```
var test ='<html> <body>' + '<h1>The Header</h1>'  +  '<p>The paragraph of text</p>' + '</body>  </html>';


this._toastr.error(test);
 _toastr : is my service.
 .error  : is my function in which I have to pass htmlContent
```

**My code**

```
var test = '<html> <body>' + '<h1>The Header</h1>'  +  '<p>The paragraph of text</p>' + '</body>  </html>';

this._toastr.error(test);
```

OUTPUT SHOULD BE:-
The prices for the below xxx/ xxx have already been entered for 27 Nov 2018.

1. Hello world!
2. Hello people!

I want this thing in toster(snackbar)

[image: Need Output like this which should be in html table Content]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert a link into MatSnackBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949233/insert-a-link-into-matsnackbar)

Comment: no. that is different

Comment: P.S. You can't have multiple `<html>` and `<body>` elements. They can only be specified once.

Answer (score 19):

You will not get around creating a custom SnackBar component as Edric mentioned in his comment/link. Standard Angular Material SnackBars only allow you to set a `message` and `action` (as well as some configuration options).

Check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-amkhye?file=app/snackbar/snackbar.component.ts) stackblitz for a very rudimentary SnackBar component that reads an HTML string from the `data` passed to it and renders the string content as HTML in the snackbar.

**snackbar.component.ts**

```
export class SnackbarComponent { 
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public data: any,
              public snackBar: MatSnackBar) {
  }
}
```

**snackbar.component.html**

```
<div [innerHTML]="data.html"></div>
<button mat-raised-button (click)="snackBar.dismiss()">Dismiss</button>
```

Use the component like this:

```
openSnackbar() {
  this.snackBar.openFromComponent(SnackbarComponent, {
    data: {
      html: '<h1>The Header</h1><p>The paragraph of text</p>'
    }
  });
}
```

You could easily wrap it in a service if that is what you need.

Comment: it is ignoring inline styles

Comment: @Fabian stackblitz  is not available, it shows 404.